# PostgreSQL: Group by misma clave valor

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

Mediante este código

```
select o.num,r.nombre,or2.rubro_id,or2.perdesde,or2.perhasta,or2.cant,t.nombre  
from rubro r
inner join objeto_rubro or2 on r.rubro_id = or2.rubro_id 
inner join objeto o on o.obj_id = or2.obj_id 
inner join objeto_trubro t on t.cod = or2.tipo 
where o.num='P0081659' and or2.rubro_id ilike 'T%' and or2.perhasta >2021008 and or2.est = 'A'
group by o.num,r.nombre,or2.rubro_id,or2.perdesde,or2.perhasta,or2.cant,t.nombre
```

Mi inconveniente es que quisiera poder agrupar solamente por or2.rubro_id ya que tengo un caso que con el código anterior no se agrupa correctamente ya que tienen fecha y/o cantidad distintas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que en tu modelo de datos el objeto P0081659 ha tenido más de un rubro, ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer en esos caso? ahora estarías mostrando todos.

Comment: Mostrar un solo registro ya que todos comparten el mismo rubro_id T6320001